# Node.js: Socket.io+MEAN.js - can't emit right after connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, meanjs

I'm quite new to the Node.js and I currently have a problem to make mean.js + socket.io work properly.

In a nutschel, the client does not receive the events emitted in the `on('connection',...)` handler, but it receives other events.

To demonstrate my probleme, I reproduced it on a base mean.js application.

Steps to reproduce:

1. install mean.js:
   npm install -g generator-meanjs
   yo meanjs
2. Replace server.js with this one https://gist.github.com/Nihaux/c02d61f6572d6531b60c
   (setup socket.io)
3. Replace app/views/layout.server.view.hmtl with this one https://gist.github.com/Nihaux/05041ff4a33f0f5c7508 (launch socket io and add a link to send an event)
4. Optional comment line 67 in config/express.js to disable express logger (too much noise).
5. Run DEBUG=socket* node server.js
6. With google-chrome, open the debug bar, on the network tab, websocket filter
7. Goto localhost:3000. The websocket should appear: on the frame tab I have
   5
   3probe
   2probe
   => I should have received a "hello" msg
8. Scroll at the bottom of the page and click on "TEST ME"
   after refreshing the frame tab (by click on another tab then back to frame tab) I can see:
   42["test:received",{"data":"test"}] ==> the message the server sent me back
   42["test"] ==> the message I sent
   5
   3probe
   2probe

Please, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
In fact the client does receive the event, but google-chrome does not shows it on the frame panel.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://vexxhost.com/blog/mean-socket-io-integration-tutorial/) is a pretty straightforward way to get Socket.IO integrated and working with a base MEAN.JS project. Hope this helps.